# JavaScript Error: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

Tags: javascript

i am working on a web application that will play a song from JS. The code that I have is:

```
const song =  {
    play: () => {
        document.querySelector('body .audio').play();
    },
    pause: () => {
        document.querySelector('body .audio').pause();
    }
};
```

When i call song.play(), I get an error in the console:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

No more, just that. I have tried to search the internet but nothing can give me the answer. How can I solve this problem.

**Update:** I have done some more research, and it turns out that i can call the exact same script from the console and it works, but not from a script.

Comment: Can you also share your HTML with us?

Comment: Your code looks fine. You probably have a problem with the selector. Try to add this at the beginning of `play` function: `console.log(document.querySelector('body .audio'));`. Does it print something other than `null`?

Comment: Try this piece of code `document.querySelector('body .audio').play().catch(e => console.log(e));`and tell us the detail of the logged exception

Comment: @Baboo_ I've tried it, it just says DOMException

Answer (score 1):

[Autoplay Policy Changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

```
var promise = document.querySelector('audio').play();

if (promise !== undefined) {
  promise.then(_ => {
    // Autoplay started!
  }).catch(error => {
    // Autoplay was prevented.
    // Show a "Play" button so that user can start playback.
  });
}
```